# Permalinks do not work on Event subpages

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with permalink. When I set "Post name" option, I get "Page not found".

I have an event page: url is http://mydomain.com/events/event-1/
This event page has 3 static pages, one of the urls is http://mydomain.com/event-1/about/, http://mydomain.com/event-1/register/... I get 404 error on this page. Event is a parent of this 3 static pages. Static I just meant Wordpress pages.

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Read this page:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

If you are using Apache, make sure that the FollowSymLinks option is enabled and that the FileInfo directive is allowed.

Comment: All other pages and posts work GREAT! This 3 pages have parent that is a custom post type "event". If I change the parent to page, everything work.

Comment: What events plugin are you using?

Comment: Try re-saving your WordPress permalink settings in Settings > Permalinks from your admin area. When testing after deactivating plugins and switching themes. you should re-save your permalinks after deactivating/switching.

Comment: Unfortunately by re-saving WordPress permalink do not help. I get the same error.